# Global isothermal coordinates for particular surfaces of revolution

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

My question is related to the uniformization theorem. But not being an expert on this, I am not sure if my question is covered by this result. Before going deeply into the question, I would like to know if one of you already has an answer to my question.

Here comes the question.

Let $\varphi \in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$ be an *even* function. Consider the graph of $\varphi$ in the $x z$-plane and the surface $S$ obtained by rotating the graph of $\varphi$ around the $z$ axis. A global orthogonal parameterization of $S$ is given by
$$
(u,v)\in\mathbb{R}^2 \mapsto (x(u) \mathrm{sech}(v),x(u) \mathrm{tanh} (v), z(u))
$$
where $(x(u),z(u))$ is a parameterization of the graph of $\varphi$. But this parameterization of $S$ is, in general, not isothermal.

Is it true that $S$ admits a global isothermal parameterization $\Phi:\mathbb{R}^2\to S$?

Comment: Yes, of course, because it has zero curvature outside of a compact subset.

Comment: @MoisheKohan this is great news for me. Could you give me a reference where I can read this type of statement? Maybe you can also answer this further question. I imagine that the parameterization $\Phi$ that gives this global parameterization has to satisfy a PDE. Is it known which PDE has to be in this very particular case? This will be really helpful!

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko, $\varphi$ is of compact support, therefore outside of the support of $\varphi$ the surface $S$ is nothing but a plane.

Comment: @Kosh: Sorry, I did not notice the condition about $C_c^\infty$. But it is true without this condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a consequence of the Uniformization Theorem (UT) and Riemann's theorem on removable singularities:

1. By the $UT$, $S$ is conformal either to the open unit disk $\Delta$ or to the complex plane.
2. Suppose that $S$ is conformal to $\Delta$. Observe that the complement to a large disk in $S$ is contained in the $xy$-plane (by the compact support assumption), hence, is conformal to the punctured disk $\Delta^*=\Delta \setminus \{0\}$. Suppose that $f: S\to \Delta$ is a conformal mapping. Restricting $f$ to $C$, we obtain a conformal mapping of  $\Delta^*$ onto $\Delta \setminus K$, where $K\subset \Delta$ is a compact. Since this restriction  is bounded, by Riemann's theorem it extends holomorphically to $0$. But this extension cannot exist since it would contradict, for instance, the Maximum Principle. qed

See my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2561435/simply-connected-noncompact-complete-2-dimensional-submanifold-of-mathbbr3/2564854#2564854) for more references, in particular, to the example of Osserman of the graph of a function which is conformal to the unit disk.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, more general statement is true: if $\phi$ is any smooth function (not necessary with compact support), the surface is conformally equivalent to the plane.
This follows from the result of Milnor,

J. Milnor, On deciding whether a surface is parabolic or hyperbolic, Amer. Math. Monthly, 84, 1, 43-46,

If the metric is $ds^2=r^2+g(r)^2d\theta^2$, then the surface is parabolic (=conformally equivalent to the plane) if and only if 
$$
\int^\infty \frac{dr}{g(r)}=\infty.$$
In our case we can take $g(r)=r/\sqrt{1+(\partial\phi/\partial r)^2}$
and the integral in Milnor's criterion is always divergent.

Comment: Thanks! I have taken a look at the paper (https://www.jstor.org/stable/2318308) together with your answer. So the "explicit construction" is the one in the paper (and used in your answer)? One introduces geodesic polar coordinates and then one introduces $\rho(r):=\int_a^r ds /g(s)$ ?

PS. I guess you mean $ds^2=dr^2+..$. And there is a limit of integration missing.
PS2. I would really appreciate if you could write down the final answer. I mean the expression of the parameterization $\Phi(\theta,\rho)\to ...$ with $\rho$ given by...